# Efficiently truncate string "float" in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a string that can be like this: "100.4", "100.4867", "100.0".  I'd like to truncate it so that it has at most two digits after the period.  So for example: "100.4", "100.48", "100.0".  What's an efficient way to do this in Erlang?

Comment: You don't want "100.4867" to be rounded to "100.49"?

Comment: @RichN - Either way's fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you sure, that strings contains right representation of float , can do, for example, so:

```
List = [  "100.4", "100.4867", "100.0"].
[fun()->lists:sublist(X,string:chr(X,$.)+2) end() || X<-List].
```

and result:

```
["100.4","100.48","100.0"]
```

if no - add the processing of these cases.

As rightly noted Lyn Headley in the comments anonymous function here is not required, and you can do so:

```
[lists:sublist(X,string:chr(X,$.)+2) || X<-List].
```

Comment: why the anonymous function?

Comment: @LynHeadley, thanks. It's habit, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I would replace string:chr/2 with string:rstr/2

Answer (score 2):

If you ask about **efficient** implementation:

```
trunc([]) -> [];   %% or raise exception because it is not a float
trunc(".") -> [];  %% or "." = L) -> L or raise exception or ".0" or what ever you want
trunc([$.,_] = L) -> L;
trunc([$.,_,_] = L) -> L;
trunc([$.,X,Y|_]) -> [$.,X,Y];
trunc([H|T]) -> [H|trunc(T)].
```